# Getting static GZIP file via HTTP and auto extracting works only in IE - why?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, http, google-chrome

So I am making a request to my server for a static `*.gz` file like this:

```
Request URL:https://1.2.3.4:9090/arch/archive.csv.gz
Request Method:GET
```

I want the file to be automitacally deflated and saved as csv when user tries to access it from browser, so I set the response headers in a filter like this:

```
    //....

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    String path = req.getServletPath();

        res.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        res.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.lastIndexOf("."));
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
   //....
```

So after making a get request I see the following response in Chrome Developer tools:

```
* Response Headers *:
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Disposition:filename=archive.csv
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:342208
Content-Type:application/x-gzip;charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 08 Jan 2014 09:54:35 GMT
ETag:W/"342208-1389113112000"
Last-Modified:Tue, 07 Jan 2014 16:45:12 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

This works great in Internet Explorer - the file is downloaded and saved as CSV - everything is fine. However when I try to do the same in Chrome/Firefox the file is ineed saved as CSV file but is not decompressed (despite the csv extension the file is actually a GZ archive).

Why does it work this way? How can I make it work under all browsers?

Comment: I've just run a test using the same headers that you've specified above and the csv file is decompressed fine for me in both Chrome/Firefox. However, I'm running Ubuntu, not Windows. Perhaps it's a platform (Windows specific) issue?

Comment: My platform is Windows 7 Prof, SP1, x64. The Chrome version is 31.0.1650.63 m

Comment: try this: remove gzip from encoding, add ".gz" to filename, change content-type to "application/x-gzip"